# Mounting whole-disk filesystems in Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, openstack, disk-image

I am booting a Windows instance in an OpenStack environment.  OpenStack can use a "configuration drive" to pass information into the instance.  This drive is formatted as a whole-disk MS-DOS filesystem (i.e., there is no partition map).

Is there any way to mount this under Windows?  Windows can see the disk, but because there is no partition map it shows it all as "Unallocated".